# What replaces NSURL -URLHandleUsingCache

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I have the following code that I'm upgrading to the latest Mac OSX sdk.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
CURLHandle *handle = (CURLHandle*) [url URLHandleUsingCache: NO];
```

I get a compiler warning indicating that URLHandleUsingCache has been deprecated, but the documentation doesn't list a replacement.  I've looked around and seen indications that NSURLConnection should be used instead of the NSURLLoading protocol.

So far, I've been unsuccessful in finding the appropriate replacement.  Which method/class combination should I use?